# Can I use javascript to call delphi xe8 REST service post?

Tags: javascript, rest, delphi, post, datasnap

Getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` on browser (Crome).

Server Delphi XE8 REST service exe program:

```
function TServerMethods.updateInsertData4(val1: string): string;
begin
  result := val1;
end;
```

Javascript:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://..hods/InsertData4", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.json = false;
xmlhttp.timeout = 1000 * 10;
xmlhttp.ontimeout = function () { alert("Timed out!!!"); }
xmlhttp.onerror = function () { alert("error"); }
xmlhttp.send('data');
```

Comment: The answer to your question as asked is Yes, you can. However, I'm not understanding what your problem is which you're trying to solve. What are you using in Delphi as your REST server?

Comment: See http://delphi.org/2015/04/cors-on-datasnap-rest-server/

Comment: You've searched for that error message, right? You've read about it and understand what it means? So what part are you missing from your program? What trouble are you having with the solution?

Answer (score 1):

From [CORS on DataSnap REST Server](http://delphi.org/2015/04/cors-on-datasnap-rest-server/):

> All you need to do is add a custom header in the Response before
>   dispatching the result on the DataSnap server

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  //allows cross domain calls
  Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','yourdomain.com');
  if FServerFunctionInvokerAction <> nil then
    FServerFunctionInvokerAction.Enabled := AllowServerFunctionInvoker;
end;
```

Note that the original example used '*' instead of a domain name (yourdomain.com), which would allow any third party to access your REST server.